# How do I extract the second occurence of a character?

Tags: java, regex, substring

How do I extract '1358751074-6824' from this

```
http://api.discogs.com/images/R-1169056-1358751074-6824.jpeg
```

and it also needs to extract '13587510746824' from this

```
http://api.discogs.com/images/R-1169056-13587510746824.jpeg
```

So I thought I could do it by substringing from the 'second - of the last path component up to the final dot', but how do I work out the **second** -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work out the position of the second dash without regular expressions - by finding the position of the first dash, and working from there:

```
int pos = str.indexOf('-', str.indexOf('-')+1);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/3vxlr2)

Comment: Thanks thats the simplest approach.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the allowed variations of the string, you could do something like:

```
String extract = s.replaceAll(".*?-.*?-([\\d-]+).*", "$1");
```

- `.*?-` skips everyhing up to the first hyphen
- `.*?-` skips everything up to the second hyphen
- `([\\d-]+)` is the part you want to keep: digits and hyphens
- `.*` skips the rest of the string

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this time Ive gone with the nonregexp option as easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// Your original String
String str = "http://api.discogs.com/images/R-1169056-1358751074-6824.jpeg";

// identify the one-before-last-dash
int i=str.lastIndexOf("-", str.lastIndexOf("-")-1);

// Extract the value you want
String newStr = str.substring(i+1, str.lastIndexOf("."));

// Return numeric value only
String strNums = newStr.replaceAll("[^?0-9]+", "");
```